# While adding Firebase SDK to Android Studio error : Could not find method plugins() for arguments

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to add Firebase SDK to Android project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

error message:

```
> Build file 'C:\\Users\\Admin1\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\build.gradle' line: 7
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'My Application'.
> Could not find method plugins() for arguments \[build_arjjpsftc7rcjw6ntcnbana8l$\_run_closure1$\_closure3@22dd2f7f\] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```

Comment: You're editing the wrong Gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `plugins{}` block to top of your file and outside of your `buildscript{}` block

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}
```